# Select task from Trax loop

Tags: python, trax

I have a Trax loop object, from which I would like to extract a task object. The code below returns the error `AttributeError: 'Loop' object has no attribute '_task'`. Do you have suggestions on how to fix this?

Background info: I am trying to run on a GPU setting the code of W4 assignement of the Coursera course "[Natural Language Processign with Attention Models](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/attention-models-in-nlp/course-4-introduction-EXHcS)".

```
test_loop = training_loop(ReformerLM, train_stream, eval_stream)
type(test_loop)
train_task = test_loop._task
```

Here is the error message:

```
<class 'trax.supervised.training.Loop'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-937f26e690d0> in <module>
      1 test_loop = training_loop(ReformerLM, train_stream, eval_stream)
      2 print(type(test_loop))
----> 3 train_task = test_loop._task
      4 #eval_task = test_loop._eval_task
      5 

AttributeError: 'Loop' object has no attribute '_task'
```

Comment: The code runs fine in the Coursera notebook... is it because they use TPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No access to the coursera course:/, can you try the following properties?

1. `test_loop.tasks`, which returns the training tasks.
2. `test_loop.eval_tasks`, which returns the evaluation tasks.

You can find more properties from trax doc: https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trax.supervised.html#trax.supervised.training.Loop.tasks